# Finding nth Match in a List in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel from A1:A5

```
a  
a  
b  
a  
b
```

I want to find the row of the nth occurrence of the value 'a' using Excel Functions and not VBA

- If I put in 1 into this function, I want to get 1.
- If I put in 2 into this function, I want to get 2.
- If I put in 3 into this function, I want to get 4

A solution that works is to add the following formula
`=COUNTIF($A5:A5,"a")` in B1 and then drag it down to B5.

I can then use `=MATCH(C1,B1:B5,0)` where C1 holds the variable n.

However is there a neater way without having to add extra columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(myMatch=myRange)*ROW(myRange),Occurrence)
```

The `1/(..)` portion of the formula converts non-matches to `DIV/0!` errors, which the `AGGREGATE` function can ignore.  So the Smallest value will be the first matching value; etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this should work **ARRAY FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=SMALL(IF(C1=$A$1:$A$5,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),$C$2)
```

[image]