# Is there a way to automate VLOOKUP in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an excel table with column 1 like a,b,c,a,d,e,a,b and column 2 with some numbers 1,2,3,4,5... 
I use vlookup to scan the table for say 'a' and give its corresponding number which returns the value for the first instance of a.

How do I make excel return it for the next time a is mentioned? It is a huge table and I cannot modify the array each time.

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377211/finding-nth-match-in-a-list-in-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding nth Match in a List in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377211/finding-nth-match-in-a-list-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

To extract the corresponding numbers for each instance "a", just write:

```
=FILTER(B2:B100,A2:A100="a")
```

If you want the nth instance, that's as easy as writing:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B2:B100,A2:A100="a"),nth)
```